# Confusion about for loop in c: increment logic in c language

Tags: c, for-loop, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

I have a confusion in basic concept  for C language for loop increment. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int j=0;int a;
    for(j;j<=3;++j)
    {
        printf("hello\n");
        a=j;
    }
    printf("%d,%d\n",j,a);
}
```

My question is: Why is the output of a not equal to output of j? I was thinking that if `j` is getting increased for every iteration and the value of `j` is being stored in `a`, then why is a not the same?

Comment: Because `j` is incremented after it is assigned to `a`.  (I'd not write the `j` in the first section of the `for` loop control either.  It does nothing.  I'd either write `for (j = 0; j <= 3; j++)` (and omit the initialization in the variable definition) or `for ( ; j <= 3; j++)`.  I'd probably use `< 4` rather than `<= 3` too; it's more orthodox C in general, not least because it is the correct way to iterate of an array of 4 elements.  However, these parenthetical observations are tangential to your main concern.)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler ! Now my confusion is cleared. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should be bit carefull,when we are using prefix incrementation in a looping concept.

`For j=0 a=0`       # 1st iteration

`For j=1 a=1`        #2nd iteration

`For j=2 a=2`           # 3rd iteration

`For j=3 a=3`               #4th iteration

For `j=4` as the condition is not satisfied, control comes out of the for loop. But the `j` value is incremented earlier so  it outputs `"4"`.

Answer (score 1):

Till `j<=3` condition the value of `j` is assigned to `a` but after that when `j` is incremented by 1 (j==4), it breaks out from the loop as the value of `j` is now `4` and it didn't assign the value of `j` to `a`. So finally we get `a=4` and `j=3`.

Answer (score 1):

For `j=0` a=0

For `j=1` a=1

For `j=2` a=2

For `j=3` a=3

For `j=4`loop get terminated as `j<=3`become false, so j value is 4 and a value is 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the way the 3 expressions in the for-loop are executed.

Consider

```
for( exp1; exp2; exp3)
{
    body;
}
```

this will be executed like:

```
exp1;
if (exp2 == false) goto end_of_loop;
body;
exp3;
if (exp2 == false) goto end_of_loop;
body;
exp3;
if (exp2 == false) goto end_of_loop;
body;
exp3;
if (exp2 == false) goto end_of_loop;
. . . 
. . .

end_of_loop:
```

As you can see `exp3` is always executed one time after `body`.

So in your case `j` will be incremented one time after it was assigned to `a`.
 Like:

```
 a=j; // part of body
 ++j; // exp3
 j<=3 (exp2) becomes false and the loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop checks the condition at every iteration. So when you initialized `j=0`, gave the condition that the following code be looped till `j<=3` while incrementing the value of `j` after every iteration, the loop does the same.

So for the first iteration, j is 0 and hence the condition is satisfied and `a` is assigned the value of `j`. Now the value of `j` is incremented by 1. It goes on till j=3.

When j=3, a is also equal to 3. Now, the value of j is incremented by 1 and it equals 4. Now the condition is checked. Since `j!=3`, the loop breaks and you move out of the loop. Hence, although j=4, a is still 3.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1st:

```
 j = 0 
 j <= 3 => print hello and a = 0, ++j
```

2nd:

```
 j = 1
 j <= 3 => print hello and a = 1, ++j
```

3rd:

```
 j = 2
 j <= 3 => print hello and a = 2, ++j
```

4th:

```
 j = 3
 j <= 3 => print hello and a = 3, ++j
```

5th:

```
 j = 4 not satisfy j <= 3
```

So j = 4 and a =3